# How to get values from Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get the values inside my Firestore document which has a sub collection.

**ADD DATA TO DB**

In adding, what I try to accomplish is on the `userPolls` collection, I need to add a document with an `Id` based on the `userId` then create a collection of 'dailyPolls' that has a document with an `Id` of the current date but without the '/' and in it is where I put all my data like so:

```
final CollectionReference userPollCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('userPolls');
Future setPoll(UserPoll userPoll) async {
    var dt = userPoll.pollDate.replaceAll('/', '');
    return await userPollCollection
        .document(userId)
        .collection('daillyPolls')
        .document(dt)
        .setData({
      'uid': userId,
      'pollDate': userPoll.pollDate,
      'status': userPoll.status,
      'statusCode': userPoll.statusCode
    });
  }
```

**QUERYING DATA FROM DB**

In retrieving data, I need to get to the `userPolls`, then get the document with an `Id` which is the `userId`, then go to the collection of `dailyPolls`, then get the document with an `Id` which is based on the current date without the '/' then get the data which is inside it.

```
 Future getPoll() async {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd');
    final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    var pollDate = formatted;
    var dt = pollDate.replaceAll('/', '');

    var docRef = userPollCollection
        .document(userId)
        .collection('dailyPolls')
        .document(dt);

    docRef.get().then((onValue) {
      print(onValue.data);
    });
  }
```

[image]

The red square is the path and the blue is what I need

I am very new to flat databases.

Comment: I tried this code with .documents and it not work with me .. 
should be .doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the classes are you are trying to use, but here is the simplest way I can get a date in the right format:

```
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd');
final String formatted = formatter.format(now);

print(formatted);

var docRef = userPollCollection
    .document(userId)
    .collection('dailyPolls')
    .document(formatted);
```

To then get the status field, you'd do:

```
docRef.get().then((onValue) {
  print(onValue.data().status);
});
```

If you're still having problem, check the output of the first `print` statement to see if its value matches what you see in the database.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear Sir. What I am trying to get Sir is the data of the document `20200826`. I need the 'status' property so I can compare it against something.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to get that specific field. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: Thank you Sir. I changed the way I save my data so it'll be easier for me to get the result. But your suggestion helped me.